# Where can I edit my app's permissions on Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

My app has been rejected due to my wrong description of why the app needs to access CALL LOG / PHONE HISTORY.

Where can I edit this on Play Console? I could not find it yet in order to change it.

Comment: When use this permission in your app. Fill the form under Release management and describe why you are use this permission.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in your manifest file and before using the mentioned feature, make sure to ask for the user's permission. Hopefully your app will be approved.